# How to create a line graph on Excel which have very different values

Tags: excel, graph, line

I have a question about plotting a line graph on Excel.

I have 4 variables (say a, b, c, and d) which will be plotted on the vertical axis against one other variable (say x) which will be plotted on the horizontal axis.

Now variables a and b have large values in the millions where as variables c and d have very small values less than 1.

Is it possible to plot this on one line graph instead of having to create two graphs? (i.e a graph for the large values and a graph for the small values)

As the scale is so big for the large data values, the two small data values appear on top of each other and is unclear.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes... You can create second vertical axis either for a and b or for c and d.. Just keep in mind you can define where the x(horizontal) axis crosses at the left(first) vertical axis. Add all the series (a, b, c, and d) and then right click one by one those you want to take to the second vertical axis and select "Format Data Series" and then select secondary axis in the series options

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you know of an online tutorial on how to do this? I am unsure.

Comment: answer edited ... and watch this video at 16th second to add secondary axis ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpR8QvC6pAA

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. This secondary axis has solved my problem.